# How to deploy JSP Project to LAN Using Apache Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, web-deployment

I want to Deploy my JSP Project online locally. I wish that my application can be accessed from other computer on LAN by using a website type url. Any One please Help me how I can deploy my Project. 
I wish That my application can be accessed using www.online.attendance.com.pk
How to deploy like this?

Answer (score 0):

Locally it can be accessed using your IP address. Or on local network, you can update your name server to map to your IP address so that others can access it using an easier name.

While  if you want it to be accessible from internet, it would not be quite simple.

1. If you host it yourself, you would require few things in place, like NS entry(ies), Public host(public IP or port-forwarding) for your App, Appropriate DNS entries etc.
2. You could find a host provider for your application. Still you would have to add above mentioned things, like C Name record etc. But it could be possible that your app hosting service may do necessary configuration for you.